# Editor issue with the '}' key

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

Hi,

I have a keyboard issue with the '}' key. At the moment, I have to actually copy/paste this character whenever I want to use it inside a 'question' or 'answer' WYSIWYG editor on this website. If I type it using my keyboard it is replaced automatically by

```
enter your code here
```

if I am at the beginning of a line or by

```
`enter your code here`
```

if I am not.

I am using an AZERTY keyboard (being French).

On an azerty keyboard, the '}' character is two keys to the right of the '0' character and requires the 'ALT-GR' key (right of the space key) to be pressed for activation, I was wondering if this could be misinterpreted by the editor.

It does make typing code bothersome, especially since I am mostly a C++ user!

EDIT:
Following an answer: Yes I use Firefox 3.5 on Windows XP.

I'd rather not change my language though, I prefer my keys to actually reflect the characters they will produce.

For any idea or suggestion...

Comment: FYI: once configured, toggling between keyboard layouts involves pressing `Left Alt` + `Shift`. Still an annoyance, I admit, but perhaps more convenient than some other options.

Comment: Issue has been fixed, though whether because of a change in stack overflow or Firefox I have no idea... it's great though!

Answer (score 1):

Using a [UK keyboard map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#United_Kingdom), I see the same behaviour (`Alt Gr`+`=`), but only with Firefox on Windows (Chrome on Windows, IE and Firefox on Ubuntu do not respond to the key-combination).

You might want to confirm your OS, browser, versions and so on if you want a fix.

As a temporary workaround, you can try switching browsers and/or making use of your operating system's input services to remap the keyboard (for example, Windows lets you switch language input at will via a taskbar icon).

Answer (score 0):

There must be a conflict between your '}' key and the shortcut assigned to "code sample" (ctrl-k).

I can only say that while I also have an AZERTY keyboard (being Belgian), I don't have this issue. Granted, my '}' sign is on the '0' key, not two keys right of it, but I also have to use the 'ALT-GR' key to type it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is now fixed, but before I was using [ALT + 125] to write a '}' character...