# Please do not hijack command-Q

Tags: bug, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there a way to disable the hotkeys?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2980/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-hotkeys)
>   [Option to disable keyboard shortcuts in WMD](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3245/option-to-disable-keyboard-shortcuts-in-wmd)

When I am editing a question and hit command-Q I expect the browser to quit.  Instead there is some javascript hijacking my command keys for blockquote.  Either check the platform before using modifier keys or skip the keyboard shortcuts altogether.

Comment: Dupe(ish) of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3245/option-to-disable-keyboard-shortcuts-in-wmd http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2980/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-hotkeys http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24541/editor-issue-with-the-key

Comment: i'm not as mac-familiar as i should be.  is command-Q the mac equivalent of windows' Alt-F4 ("close this window now")? or even Ctrl-F4 ("close this tab now")?  if so i'd tend to agree.  surely there's a better shortcut for "blockquote".

Comment: It hijacks ^R too! grr.

Comment: see [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2980/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-hotkeys/45314#45314) for the means to disable with greasemonkey.  script not included, tho if someone's bored...

Comment: @quack: Command-Q should really be Apple-Q (he might be hitting the Control key) and it's the Application Quit shortcut. Command / Apple - W should be Close Window / Tab shortcut.

Comment: @Josh On Apple keyboards, for a few years now, there has not been an Apple logo on the Command key and all documentation refers to the "Command key", so the OP is right

Comment: @quack: it's common on Unix too. `Ctrl`+`Q` is the exit command on lots of apps (I first learnt this with FF, years ago - bad choice to put close tab and close app so close together) on Unix/X land.

Comment: @waiwai: I can't believe it. That's really depressing in two ways. First that they get rid of the Apple key, which is just iconic. Second it shows how much I've been using "modern" hardware. My key says "Command" but includes the little cloverleaf.

Comment: Hmm, this isn't a dupe of the questions it's been closed as a dupe of. I don't want to turn off the shortcuts, I just want the shortcuts not to collide with system norms. Imagine if the shortcut for block quote on Windows was alt-F4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Javascript should **never** hijack commands. **Ever**. There is no defined ruleset for editing or posting so these commands are uselessly site-specific.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't even aware you *could* hijack Command-Q! I thought that was a universal "Quit this application" and I am surprised that Safari allows that to be passed to JavaScript. I tested it however and yes, it activates a blockquote.

This should be *Control-Q* instead on Mac.

Comment: The gmail editor has this behavior - Almost.  It uses the control keys for all platforms.  On Mac, this means that it doesn't interfere with the normal shortcuts.  What do you suggest for Windows users?

Answer (score 0):

Click outside the textbox, and use Command+Q, you would get expected behavior.

Comment: That's not the point. The point is that Command-Q should behave properly *inside* the textbox!